# Different Possible Combinations from Different Sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have 4 different sets A={a,b} B={c,d} C={e,f,g,h} D={h,i}

I want to find the sum of distinct 2,3,4 letter combinations. Two letters cannot be chosen from the same set.

(i.e) For a 3 letter combination ace is valid but not abc since both a and b are from set A.

I have manually calculated for this set.

**For 2 letters there are 30 possible combinations.**
**For 3 letters there are 44 possible combinations.**
**For 4 letters there are 24 possible combinations.**

I want a generalized formula for the above question when for different size of set n(say my limit is 1000) and for variable size of elements inside each set.